# Not getting random numbers in output

Tags: java, io

This program creates a file named datafile.txt and is supposed to write 100 integers created randomly into the file using text I/O.  However, my output is "java.util.Random@30c221" 100 times.  How do I get 100 random numbers instead?  Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab5 {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //Open file to write to
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("F:\\IT311\\datafile.txt");


    int index = 0;

    //Convert FileOutputStream into PrintStream 
    PrintStream myOutput = new PrintStream(fout);
    Random numbers = new Random();
        //Declare array
        int array[] = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
        //get the int from Random Class
        array[i] = (numbers.nextInt(100) + 1);

        myOutput.print(numbers + " ");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myOutput.print(numbers + " ");
```

You are printing `Random` class instance here.

You need to do  something like:

```
myOutput.print(numbers.nextInt(100)+ " ");
```

Read [Random class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

EDIT:

No, just `array` will print again similar output (Object String), if you want to output the random value stored in array, you need to do something like:

```
myOutput.print(array[i] + " ");
```

Comment: So should it be myOutput.print(array + " "); ?

Comment: or array[i] would be better :)

Comment: @nachokk - `print(array ...` won't do what you expect!!!  See numerous Questions on how to format an array in Java.

Comment: Sorry, guys.  I didn't see the rest of Nambari's answer before I commented.  myOutput.print(array[i] + " "); worked.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nachokk - Try it and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random numbers = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    myOutput.printf("%d\n",numbers.nextInt(100)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
myOutput.print(numbers + " ");
```

with this piece of code

```
myOutput.print(array[i] + " ");
```

as the newly generated random numbers are now present in the `array`.